# NSTextView, how do I make a typewriter?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

The user has made an opinion, but I don't know how to achieve it.

The user hopes to send a "DaDa" sound like a typewriter in the NSTextView, when the keyboard is entered with the keyboard, and the default setting is not found. How do I finish this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a subclass of `NSTextView`. In your subclass, override `keyDown:`. In your `keyDown:` override, play a sound using an instance of `NSSound`.

Comment: Do you have to make a sound once every letter? It's a little bad.

Comment: No, you can create a single instance of `NSSound` and send it the `play` message each time you want to play it.